# How to manage disable/enable Minimize,Resize and Close button in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

i need to manage disable/enable Minimize,Resize and Close button by programming in oracle mdi parent forms in 10g. Please give me solution of this problems. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3CCx.png)

Comment: Why do you want to do this thing? How/when do you want to do this?

Comment: Mainly i need fixed mdi parent window size. Don't re-sizable window.

Comment: If I were your user, I certainly wouldn't want you to restrict those options.

Comment: I agree with @Littlefoot. Users have an expectation of how an application should work, based on how other applications they use. Breaking standard conventions - like being able to minimize or maximize application windows - is poor UX. If your application doesn't behave the ways its users expect they will start to distrust it. You should try to find ways to make users like your application instead of finding ways to make them hate it.

Comment: I am going to ensure users facility. User facility depend on environment.
We are making ERP software and Providing ERP software more than 10 group of company in two countries. Specialized area of our ERP is Providing garments solutions.
When open child window then facing some problems form MDI parent form closing issue. 
Please see this videos then you will understand my issue. 
[https://youtu.be/LNDzg-lyOt0]
Thanks to all of you APC and @Littlefoot
So, hopefully you will give me solutions. 
I'm waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of reasons why you might want to prevent a user from being able to resize or close an application's MDI window.  A perfect example would be if all the objects in the application are of a fixed size.  Being able to resize the parent window would do nothing more than expose unused space. Try running Microsoft Calculator. Notice you cannot resize its window. Preventing users from not resizing certainly isn't uncommon.

So to a solution...

If you were using Forms 12.2.1+, this would be easy. In v12, Forms offers two new parameters; "isResizable" and "alwaysOnTop".  Hopefully each are obvious in what they do.  Simple set to TRUE or FALSE and your done.

For v11 and older, it becomes a little ugly.  I will assume you are using separateFrame=true.  For resizing or closing you could create a Java Bean, but that likely would be more effort than it's worth.

In PL/SQL, users attempting to close the parent window (separateFrame window) doing something like the following:

1. Create an Alert object and name it "PAUSE_EXIT". The alert should include two buttons (e.g. Yes/No).
2. Create a form level WHEN-WINDOW-CLOSED trigger and add this:

---

```
do_key('EXIT');
```

3. Create a form level KEY-EXIT trigger and add something like the following. You will have to adapt it to do the right thing in your app. You will need to account for all the "windows" in your module.

---

```
DECLARE
    al_id Alert; 
    al_button NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    IF :System.Event_Window = 'FORMS_MDI_WINDOW' THEN
        al_button := Show_Alert('PAUSE_EXIT'); 
    IF al_button = ALERT_BUTTON1 THEN 
        -- User selected YES, so exit.
        EXIT_FORM; 
    ELSE
        -- User selected NO, so don't exit.
        RAISE Form_Trigger_Failure; 
    END IF; 
ELSE
    -- User attempted to close a form window and not the MDI window 
    -- Remove NULL and do something else if not the MDI window
    NULL;
END IF;
END;
```

---

A similar approach could be used to detect if the MDI window has been minimized or resized. Look in the Builder Help for these:  SYSTEM.EVENT_WINDOW, GET_WINDOW_STATE, WHEN-WINDOW-RESIZE